# How can I use GtkTreeStore in functions which receives GtkTreeModel

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, gtk

i want to use the following code:

```
gtk_tree_model_get_path(store, &iter);
```

where the `store` is `GtkTreeStore * store`, but my c++ compiler (g++) throws me the error:

```
cannot convert «GtkTreeStore* {aka _GtkTreeStore*}» to «GtkTreeModel* {aka _GtkTreeModel*}» for argument «1» to «GtkTreePath* gtk_tree_model_get_path(GtkTreeModel*, GtkTreeIter*)»
```

so i have the temptation to write this:

```
gtk_tree_model_get_path(static_cast<GtkTreeModel *> store, &iter);
```

or this:

```
gtk_tree_model_get_path((GtkTreeModel *) store, &iter);
```

but i'm not sure it will be correct. please, suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `GtkListStore` in C programs, I use `GTK_TREE_MODEL()` to cast, e.g.:

```
GtkTreeStore *store;
GtkTreeIter iter;
GtkTreePath *path = gtk_tree_model_get_path (GTK_TREE_MODEL (store), &iter);
```

This is necessary because GtkTreeModel is an interface: `GtkListStore` does not subclass `GtkTreeModel`, it implements it.

I hope that answers your question!

Comment: that's it! thanks! i started to search something like `GTK_TREE_MODEL` but my `devhelp` found nothing for me.

Comment: By convention, all GObject-derived classes have an associated casting macro.  To get the name, convert each word in the classname to caps, and add underscores.  So `GObject` --> `G_OBJECT`, `GInputStream` --> `G_INPUT_STREAM`, etc.